# Compute previous or next date with EKRecurrenceRule

Tags: ios, eventkit

I want to compute previous date or next date from an offset `NSDate` and an `EKRecurrenceRule`. Something likes this:

```
NSDate* prevDate = [Something computePreviousDateForOffsetDate: aDate 
                                            withRecurrenceRule: aRule];

NSDate* nextDate = [Something computeNextDateForOffsetDate: aDate
                                        withRecurrenceRule: aRule];
```

I could create `Something` with simple recurrence rule, however complex rules are pretty bit tough to me. I think this is pretty commonly needed things, So I asking about this.

Do I have to spend times to implement own solution?

Answer (score 1):

After losing some time with `EKRecurrenceRule` I found an alternative solution with [ios-rrule_parser](https://github.com/FabienDiTore/ios-rrule_parser). It is easiest to use and it covers all of my needs.

For nextDate use this:

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:100 *24 *60 *60];

Scheduler * scheduler = [[Scheduler alloc] initWithDate:startDate andRule:@"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1;INTERVAL=2"];
NSArray *occurences = [scheduler occurencesBetween:startDate andDate:endDate];

NSDate *nextDate = [occurences objectAtIndex:0];
```

For previousDate just change startDate.